# How to remove a element from array in dropdown of list2 after selecting an element form list1 drop down in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two drop down lists containng same array elements. after selecting one element form list1(part1) the element shoulb be deleted from listB(part1). If I unselect the element in list1 then the element(part1) should be in array(list2) 
vice versa.

So I tried like this

```
Controller.js
$scope.list1=  [{"columnName": "part1",value: "obj1"},
               {"columnName": "part2",value: "obj2"},
               {"columnName": "part3",value: "obj3"},
               {"columnName": "part4",value: "obj4"},
               {"columnName": "part5",value: "obj5"}]


$scope.list2 = [{"columnName": "part1",value: "obj1"},
             {"columnName": "part2",value: "obj2"},
             {"columnName": "part3",value: "obj3"},
             {"columnName": "part4",value: "obj4"},
             {"columnName": "part5",value: "obj5"}]


$scope.getColumn = function(colum) {

 $scope.indexOfcolum = $scope.list2.indexOf(colum);
 $scope.removecolum = $scope.list2.splice($scope.indexOfcolum,1)
 console.log($scope.indexOfcolum ,'colum index',$scope.removecolum)
}
```

Html

```
<form>
   Xxis  <select ng-model="xcolumn" ng-options=" l1.columnName for l1 in list1"ng-change="getColumn(xcolumn)">
        <option value=""></option>
        </select>
  yAxis
 <select ng-model="xcolumn" ng-options=" l2.columnName for l2 in list2"ng-change="getColumn()">
 <option value=""></option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

Here my fiddle link :http://jsfiddle.net/soumyagangamwar/9ra59ptb/

When I unselect the(option value="") then array should contain all the elements. and If I select one value in list A(part1) that should not appear in second list. and then If I select second value in listA(part2) then part2 is disappear in listB and part1 also should in listB.

can any one please help me to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `filter` to do that instead of using `ngChange` directives.

First of all, make `ngModel` useful:

```
<select ng-model="xaxis" ng-options></select>
<select ng-model="yaxis" ng-options></select>
```

Second, to filter the selected item in another `select` and make it disappear in the current `select`, we'd like to use a `filter` in `ngOptions` directive like below:

```
<select ng-options="l1.columnName for l1 in list1 | onlyNotSelectedCouldShowHere">
```

The name `onlyNotSelectedCouldShowHere` is a little tedious, right? So we'll only use `notSelected` as the name in the real code below.  :P

To make it work, we need to create a `filter` (just appended to `myApp`):

```
myApp
  // Create a filter
  .filter('notSelected', function(){
    return function(list, target) {
      // If there is no selected item in xaxis or yaxis, return all of the items 
      if (target === undefined) return list;

      // Use Array.prototype.filter() function [ES5]
      var filtered = list.filter(function(item) {
        return item.columnName !== target.columnName;
      });
      // Return the filtered array. 
      return filtered;
    }
  });
```

After realising that we need to pass an argument to the `filter` (`yaxis` for the x select and `xaxis` for the y select), we update the html:

```
<select ng-model="xaxis" ng-options=" l1.columnName for l1 in list1 | notSelected:yaxis"></select>
<select ng-model="yaxis" ng-options=" l2.columnName for l2 in list2 | notSelected:xaxis"></select>
```

Check out [the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ra59ptb/2/).

To learn more about the `filter` in AngularJS, I've found an excellent post: *[Everything about custom filters in AngularJS](https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/) by Todd Motto*.

**Update on the early morning of 8/7/16 in China:** when `value=""` is selected, show the full list.

```
myApp.filter('notSelected', function(){
  return function(list, target) {
    // undefined: If there is no selected item in xaxis or yaxis, 
    // null     : or if value="" is selected
    // return the full list
    if (target === undefined || target === null) return list;
    var filtered = list.filter(function(item) {
      return item.columnName !== target.columnName;
    });
    // console.log(filtered);
    return filtered;
  }
});
```

Check out [the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ra59ptb/4/).

Comment: Thank you so much. But Here my requirement not satisfied.

Comment: When I unselect the(option value="") then array should contain all the elements. and If I select one value in list A(part1) that should not appear in second list. and then If I select second value in listA(part2) then part2 is disappear in listB and part1 also should in listB. can you please help me

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Hi, so the codes I provided in the answer **satisfied the latter requirement**, as I quote, "and If I select one value in list A(part1) that should not appear in second list. and then If I select second value in listA(part2) then part2 is disappear in listB and part1 also should in listB", **but not the former one**, right?

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Check out the updated answer pls. And if your requirements are all satisfied, you can vote up and accept my answer.

Comment: Thank you for help. and the post was very good that you suggested.